# How could i print after i used request.getAttribute in a jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, getattribute

In my servlet, i have:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
....
request.getSession().setAttribute("list",list);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

And in my result.jsp file, i wanted to print out the checks on website, so i tried :

```
String[] str = (String[])request.getAttribute("list");
```

But there is a error said

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

So what should i do to print the list?

Thank you.

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;` - the error is clear. You can't cast to `String[]`, you need to cast to `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: And you shouldn't even have Java code in your JSP in the first place. Use the JSP EL and the JSTL. And don't use raw types.Java 5 introduced generics in 2005. We're in 2017. There's no excuse.

Comment: @JBNizet so how to user jsp el to do this ? I am really new here.

Comment: `<c:forEach var="element" items="${list}"><c:out value="${element}"/></c:forEach>`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `list` is of type `ArrayList` not an `Array`, so try this instead :

```xml
<% 

ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("list") ;

//do something ...

%>
```

And make sure you are allowing your `jsp` to access to the `Session` using : `<%@ page session="true" %>`

---

However as @JBNizet said it's so preferable to use `jstl` expression over than Java code in the jsp pages :

1. in the servlet :

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

request.setAttribute("list" , list);

RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

2. In the Jsp :

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="element">

    //use the element here...
    ${element}

</c:forEach>
```